# WPF Problems problems uploading images to app

Tags: wpf, xaml, upload

Good day.

I'm experiencing this issue, when images not included in the project are not being shown. After reading the topics about it I applied the solutions, but still it's not working.

The idea of my simple app is 3 image galleries in 3 different tabs. Still only the first one is ready. The images are being stored in a folder inside the app, and their paths in xml file. When I upload new image it is shown only as blank. If I include it and restart the app it is displayed correctly.

This is the project in github:
[ViewModel](https://github.com/vonko/VonkoProjects/blob/master/WPF/Behavior%20Binding/ImageGalleries/ViewModels/GalleriesViewModel.cs)

You can see the code for building the paths is in the **GalleriesViewModel** in the method **UploadFirstGallery**. I'm using Uri and the format **"pack://application:,,,/images//gallery1//"** which should have fixed the issue...

Can you give me some solution?

Comment: A Pack URI like `pack://application:,,,/...` is used to load resource files from an assembly. Images loaded by such an URI have to be added to the Visual Studio project and their *Build Action* has to be set to *Resource*. To load external files, you would use a relative or absolute file URI, e.g. `new Uri("images/gallery1/image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)`.

Comment: Changed it, still not working. You can see the github updated.

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your code here in your question.

Comment: I didn't post, because the problem can be everywhere. From the arrangement of the directories to the xaml. The link points to where I suppose it's most likely to be the problem, but it can be in other places in the project.